# Having problems with layouts in Iron Router on Meteor 1.2

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I just updated my Meteor application to Meteor v.1.2.0.2 and Iron Router v.1.0.12. Iron Router keeps returning this error on the client side: `Couldn't find a template named "layout" or "layout". Are you sure you defined it?`. Nothing is rendered except for this error. Here's my routes.js file:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});

Router.route('/', function() {
    if (this.ready) {
      this.render();
    }

    else {
      this.render('loading');
    }
  },
  { name: 'main' } );

Router.route('/new/story', { name: 'newStory' } );

Router.route('/story/:_id', { name: 'viewStory', data: function() {
  return Stories.findOne(this.params._id);
},

waitOn: function () {
  return [Meteor.subscribe("story", this.params._id), Meteor.subscribe("seeds", this.params._id)];
},

onBeforeAction: function() {

    var document = Stories.find({ _id: this.params._id }).fetch();
    if ($.inArray(Meteor.user()._id, document[0].contributors) === -1) {
      this.render('addSeed');
    }

    else {
      this.next();
    }

}  } );

Router.route('/stories', { name: 'viewStories',
  waitOn: function() {
    Meteor.subscribe("stories");
  }
});

Router.route('/story/:_id/new/seed', { name: 'addSeed', data: function() {
  return Seeds.findOne(this.params._id);
}} );

Router.route('/logout', function() {
  Meteor.logout();
  Router.go("main");
});
```

The layout template looks like this:

```
<template name="layout">
  {{> nav}}
  {{> yield}}
</template>
```

I don't understand what's wrong. Please help!

Comment: Code looks ok. I can only assume that layout template has got moved somewhere where the router code can't see it, like into the server folder or something.

Comment: No, it's in the client folder.

Comment: If it all worked before updating to 1.2, and now it doesn't, you could try doing a new build. Enter the .meteor/local folder, cancel the build folder, then restart the app.

Comment: Didn't work. I'm still getting the same error as before. Could it be an outdated dependency of one of my packages?

Comment: I solved this issue removing a local package. Are you using a local package? If yes, try remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same errors after updating to Meteor v.1.2.
As it turned out the problem was at materialize package. Rollback from `0.97.1` to `0.97.0` version of materialize packcage works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have ejson package. If it's missing add it with meteor command:

```
meteor add ejson
```

Make sure you have this list of packages too:

```
meteor-base             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo                   # The database Meteor supports right now
blaze-html-templates    # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze views
session                 # Client-side reactive dictionary for your app
jquery                  # Helpful client-side library
tracker                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library
standard-minifiers      # JS/CSS minifiers run for production mode
es5-shim                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.
ecmascript              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code
autopublish             # Publish all data to the clients (for prototyping)
insecure                # Allow all DB writes from clients (for prototyping)
iron:router
ejson
```

Comment: It's been added. "ejson without a version constraint has already been added."

Comment: Good, make sure you have the list of packages listed in my edited answers. maybe there's a missing paxkage like blaze-html-templates.